# Handling touch events in order

Tags: android

I want to write a program that handles touch events in a specific order within a single activity.

For example:
A few views are shown.
If the user doesn't tap on the first view, I will show another activity.
If the user taps on it however, I want to detect a tap on the second, then the third, etc.

How can I handle multiple touch events?
I think I need an `onTouchEvent` method and in it I need an if-else statement for the first click but I don't know how I can monitor for the subsequent touch events.

Comment: Quesstion is not clear. Please rephrase.

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell it better.

Comment: Dude should improve your problem stating skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help you.I always do like this

```
public void onClick(View v){
if(v==imageView1){

//do ssomething 
}
if(v== imageView2){
//do something
}
if(v==imageView3){
//do something
}
```

like this u can do according to different button or imageview

Comment: Thanks it helped me but not fully. I don't know yet how handle events in order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the picture is an ImageView inside the main view. Why not just append touchlisteners to each view?

Comment: Yes it is an ImageView or can be a button. My problem is that I don't know how handle events in ORDER.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to do. If you use Touch Listeners, you won't have to worry about the order because each view will have a different touch listener and will only be called if that SPECIFIC view is touched.

Comment: @Jan, I think he needs to accept the clicks in order of view occurrence or something like that.

Comment: Yes for example, if the pictures on the screen appear from left to right and I want to touch them from left to right. So for example press the 1 first then 2 second 3 third etc

Answer (score 0):

Set the `onClickListener` for the n+1 view only when nth view is clicked.

Like this

```
view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     void onClick(View v) {
        view2.setOnclickListner(new Onclicklistener() {
           void onClick(View v) {
           // add further view's click listeners else do what ever if this 
           // is the last view.
           }
        });
    }

});
```

Not an elegant solution but should work IMHO.

Comment: So:
<pre>
view1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     void onClick(View v) {
            // do something
           }
view2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     void onClick(View v) {
            // do something
           }
});
<code>
It will be good? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

From your problem statement it seems you have an ordered list of views, each should have a touch listener, but the listener for the second view should not fire unless the listener for the first view has fired first.

This can easily be done by keeping a counter in your activity:
`private int highestIndexTapped`. When a view is tapped, check whether its index is such that `index == highestIndexTapped + 1`.

If it is, increase `highestIndexTapped` by 1 and fire the listener. Otherwise either eat the touch event or pass it on to the next part of your pipeline.